# JavaScript/html time

Tags: time

I'm trying to convert the normal 24 hour system to a 20 hour system in JavaScript or html

there seems to be problems and I don't know how to fix them, the program code as a whole works ok but it's not accurate in the area of displaying the proper time

can someone help me.

24hrs per day to 20hrs
60 minutes per hour to 40 minutes per hour
60 seconds per minute to 80 seconds per minute 
1000 milliseconds per second to 1350 milliseconds per second

I have been working with the code that is supposed to get the milliseconds from 1/1/1970 to make things hopefully simple but like I said the program isn't working quite right, I do have a table that lets me know what normal time would be at each changed hour but that's all the info I have

Comment: Can you attach some of the code you tried? Also, may I ask what is the purpose of this? :D

Comment: @STT 
the scripts are used here:

http://jsfiddle.net/user/Nedeku/fiddles/

Comment: I took a look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/Nedeku/NUtrx/  -- it seems to work OK. Is it showing wrong time? Can you provide that table you compare it with?

Comment: @STT
this is the table for time: http://www.thegoreancave.com/tmm/days.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z4s7j9vL/1/

My approach was to get the timestamp difference between the current time and midnight of the same day:

```
millis = ts - clone.getTime();
```

This way you get how many milliseconds have passed this day and you can do your conversion from there. This is limited to converting time only, but if months and years followed the same principles you could just convert the same way from the current timestamp.

Comment: possibly my mistake is that i am assuming that it is working based off of time zones already, if it does then the time frame may need to be offset to compensate for the time zones, if not then i don't know

Comment: I think it all depends what you are basing it off of. If it is just a JavaScript `Date` then you could make it time zone agnostic -- the timezone will be included in the `Date` and you only translate it.